# How to add a class to parent element when checkbox is checked in Vue.js 2.0

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Is it possible to use a checked state of checkbox to add a class to parent div? If not, how to do it? Here is the code:

```
<div
   class="checkbox-container"
   v-for="item in items"
   :key="item.id"
   :class="{'checked': checkbox.checked}" // I wanna do something like that
>
   <input type="checkbox" :id="item.id" :value="item.value" v-model="checkedItems">
   <label :for="item.id">{{ item.text }}</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the value from `v-model`

```
:class="{'checked': checkedItems.includes(item.value) }"
```